# I have found a system of 3 variables that lead to a quadratic equation, so how do I find the answer?/

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$p^2 + q^2 = 81$$
$$p^2 + (q-x)^2 = 225$$
$$(p-x)^2 + q^2 = 144$$
So these are the 3 equations.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Interestingly, $$144+81=?$$

Comment: If you expand the squares in the last two, the first can simplify both of them.  It doesn't get you there, but it is a start.  Subtracting the last two eliminates the squares of all three.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(p,q)=9(\cos t,\sin  t)$, then

\begin{align}
  81+x^2-18x\sin t &= 225 \\
  81+x^2-18x\cos t &= 144 \\
  (18x)^2 &= (x^2-144)^2+(x^2-63)^2 \\
  0 &= 2x^4-738x^2+24705 \\
  x &= \pm 3\sqrt{\frac{41 \pm 3\sqrt{119}}{2}} \\
  p &= 9\cos t \\
  &= \frac{x^2-63}{2x} \\
  q &= 9\sin t \\
  &= \frac{x^2-144}{2x}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
p^2+q^2 &= 81
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
p^2+q^2-2qx+x^2 &= 225
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
p^2-2px+x^2+q^2 &= 144
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Subtract \eqref{1} from \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}
to get $p$ and $q$ in terms of $x$,
\begin{align}
p &= \tfrac12\,\frac{x^2-63}x
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
q &= \tfrac12\,\frac{x^2-144}x
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

then substitute \eqref{4} \eqref{5} into \eqref{1}
to get biquadratic equation in $x$

\begin{align}
2\,(x^2)^2-738\,x^2+24705
&=0
,
\end{align}

which gives
\begin{align}
x^2&=\tfrac{369}2\pm\tfrac{27}2\,\sqrt{119}
\end{align}
and hence, four solutions for $x$:

\begin{align}
x_1&=\tfrac32\,\sqrt{82+6\sqrt{119}}
,\\
x_2&=-\tfrac32\,\sqrt{82+6\sqrt{119}}
,\\
x_3&=\tfrac32\,\sqrt{82-6\sqrt{119}}
,\\
x_4&=-\tfrac32\,\sqrt{82-6\sqrt{119}}
.
\end{align}